# pass a parameter to html partial and retrieve value inside the partial html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I pass a parameter to html partial and retrieve value inside the partial html?

```
@Html.Partial(MVC.Cans.Shared.Views.CanViewModels, Model, UserExists);
```

The logic wether UserExists is inside the partial AND I do not want to change my viewmodels for this task.

How would you solve that?

Comment: Are you wanting to pass a model plus some extra information to the partial, the access both the model and that extra information?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the 3rd parameter of `@Html.Partial` to pass additional view data to the partial

```
@Html.RenderPartial("yourPartialName", yourModel, new ViewDataDictionary { { "userExists", true} });
```

The in the partial you can access it using

```
 @ViewData["userExists"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner way would be to change the model to include that second value but if you dont want to do it, i'd say you use the Renderpartial method with takes in a View data dictionary type:

```
Html.RenderPartial(
      "partialview", 
       Model, 
       new ViewDataDictionary { { "UserExists", UserExists} }
);
```